# Why "theirs" tactic not working here when I am in merging state?

Tags: git

We can reproduce this problem by:

1. Setup

   ```
   git remote add proxy git@github.com:pingcap/tidb-engine-ext.git
   git remote add tikv git@github.com:tikv/tikv.git
   git fetch proxy 3f55709e6678c687195fbbd59662459aa348d039
   git fetch tikv b448214b8f2c0a6a9ba2381a1983ce20e6514218
   ```
2. Merge tikv's commit `b4482` into proxy at `3f557`

   ```
   git checkout -b test 3f55709e6678c687195fbbd59662459aa348d039
   git merge b448214b8f2c0a6a9ba2381a1983ce20e6514218
   ```

There are many unrelavant conflicts, so just don't look at them. We only look into `components/resolved_ts/src/endpoint.rs` at line 502, it says

```
let resolved_ts = observe_region.resolver.resolve(ts).min();
```

However, ["theirs" version](https://github.com/tikv/tikv/blob/b448214b8f2c0a6a9ba2381a1983ce20e6514218/components/resolved_ts/src/endpoint.rs#L502) is

```
let resolved_ts = observe_region.resolver.resolve(ts);
```

Now, I decide to replace the whole file with "theirs", so I run

```
git checkout --theirs components/resolved_ts
Updated 1 path from the index
```

And then I find

```
let resolved_ts = observe_region.resolver.resolve(ts).min();
```

Yes, the file is not changed into "theirs". It is weird.

However, if I run

```
git checkout b448214b8f2c0a6a9ba2381a1983ce20e6514218 -- components/resolved_ts
```

The the file is changed into "theirs". It is more weird now. Since if this works, why `git checkout --theirs` fails?

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

My toolchain is

```
git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
```

Comment: If the file is in conflict, it looks to me (by reading `git help checkout`) that just `--theirs` won't work: `The index may contain unmerged entries because of a previous failed merge. By default, if you try to check out such an entry from the index, the checkout operation will fail and nothing will be checked out. Using -f will ignore these unmerged entries`. You need to use `-f`, according to that section of the manual (take a look, just in case).

Comment: @eftshift0: this isn't the case here; it's just because the auto-merge was able to resolve everything on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the `git merge` output more closely, you will see the following:

```
Auto-merging components/resolved_ts/src/endpoint.rs
Auto-merging components/resolved_ts/src/cmd.rs
```

Compare this with, e.g.:

```
Auto-merging Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Makefile
Auto-merging Cargo.toml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Cargo.toml
```

Note how, for each of the last two files, we see first:

```
Auto-merging
```

and then:

```
CONFLICT (content):
```

followed by the file's name.  For `endpoint.rs` and `cmd.rs`, however, we see `Auto-merging` followed by ... nothing at all, indicating that the auto-merge *worked*.

If you inspect what's in the index, there's no "theirs" version left behind:

```
$ git ls-files --stage components/resolved_ts/src/endpoint.rs
100644 a4e5f6e38641e12820167e715e8666b844943f40 0  components/resolved_ts/src/endpoint.rs
```

Similarly, `git status --short` shows:

```
$ git status --short | grep components/resolved_ts/
M  components/resolved_ts/src/cmd.rs
UU components/resolved_ts/src/resolver.rs
M  components/resolved_ts/tests/mod.rs
```

Note that `endpoint.rs` is not in this list: there *was* a conflict, but it was easily auto-resolved, and Git not only resolved it, but invoked `git add` on the result.  *That's* why `--theirs` does nothing: there is no "theirs" version in the index.  The one matching `components/resolved/` path that *does* have a `theirs` version in the index—which is where:

> ```
> Updated 1 path from the index
> ```

came from above—is `UU components/resolved_ts/src/resolver.rs`.

Comment: OK, I get it, so this file is not a conflict file. I can't checkout "theirs" on a non-conflict file.